# Can we implement a openID options in a Native iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, openid

Is is possible to implement OpenId authentication in iPhone? I found a framework named [janrain](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/mobile). But with free sign up, we can avail only features. Is there any other open source framework  available?

Thanks !!

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I found no other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a solution that uses a standard UIWebView to handle the authentication.  Since cookies are shared within an app, a successful authentication with a UIWebView (that stores a session or authentication cookie) will carry over to other requests.

I don't have a formal framework, but it works like this:  I issue a REST request.  If the request returns a JSON string, then I'm already authenticated and all is good.  If the request returns a redirect (i.e., 301), then the site is trying to redirect for authentication.  Here I stop the redirect and present a modal UIWebView with the sign in page.  The user can sign in with their OpenID, and once the user is authenticated is redirected to a predetermined success url.

The UIWebView `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` delegate method checks each URL after it's loaded, and dismisses the modal once it sees that the success url was requested.

That's basically how I did it and it seems to work.

Comment: Chris, this seems to be good. Can you provide a working model or solution if you have one?

Comment: I award the bounty to Chris for providing a convincing solution. Chris it would be good, if you can get a sample demo project.

Comment: I put together a small proof of concept which demonstrates what I described.  In the app delegate set the baseURL to a URL that requires OpenID authentication.  It should also be where the user gets redirected after authentication.  Grab the code here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4361885/OpenAuthDemo.zip  I named the project OpenAuthDemo.  Should have been OpenIDDemo.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the contribution. :)

Comment: Chris would you be able to repost your solution? The link no longer works

Comment: Hi James, give it a try again.

Comment: For anyone trying this, the solution works, but for error handling its hard to manage the different scenarios that can occur within the login process delegated to the web view.

Comment: @chris Hello again, I modified your code a bit and it now works perfectly on iOS 7. But, my question is, is there a way you can retain the key, or to keep the app approved? Because, yes granted, the login does complete, but where are the authorisation keys? I need to keep those, after the user closes the app...

Comment: @isklikas - I regret I haven't done anything with this approach, so I'm probably not the best to answer. My guess is the values are stored as cookies and expire per whatever rule is set on the server.