# iPhone openID authentication and embed HTML

Tags: iphone, openid

**Question 1**

I want to make IPhone application that uses OpenID for authentication.  I have found janrain described here :
http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/05/janrain-openid-iphone-apps/   this is exactly what I want! However is commercial licenced is there any open source/free alternatives?

**Question 2**

I also want to later make Android , Windows Mobile , etc versions of my applicaion. To save making multiple application I thought I can make 80% of my application in HTML the other 20% needs a GPS so would need to be an iPhone app.   Is it possible to make an IPhone application that some of its screens are really web pages?  I do not want to open Safari I just want to embed HTML directly into an application so the user would still think they are just in the application still?

Comment: Here's some example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448863/can-we-implement-a-openid-options-in-a-native-iphone-app

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448863/can-we-implement-a-openid-options-in-a-native-iphone-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can use a HTML/CSS/Javascript solution to develop my App.

And still have access to the GPS etc.

Using http://www.phonegap.com/ and http://jqtouch.com/  etc

This should mean I can use regular OpenID or yahoos mobile phone optimised version here
http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2009/10/yahoo_openid_an/   so I can keep my solution 100% web based.