# Are there any OpenID client libraries written in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openid

I've searched google and stackoverflow, but can't find anything.

Is OpenID something people doesn't do with objective-c and/or iPhones/iPads?

Comment: Some example code is provided here: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448863/can-we-implement-a-openid-options-in-a-native-iphone-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some example code is provided here: have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448863/can-we-implement-a-openid-options-in-a-native-iphone-app).

(Reposted as full answer, as requested in comment)

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo! claims that it has an optimized implementation for iphone([link](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2009/10/yahoo_openid_an/)). Also Janrain has a [possible solution](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/mobile)(they offer a free account for testing).

hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see the relevance to my question. Yahoo! has an iPhone-optimized *login page*, not a library written in objective-c. Exactly what is the Janrain offer?

Comment: yahoo is an openID provider so you can use their accounts to login in every website that supports openId login only by poping up a uiWebView and loading the login page, no library needed(it was a solution). jarain on the other hand provides a library (https://github.com/janrain/engage.iphone/tarball/master). you should make a free account and test the functionality.

Comment: I still need a client library to access the server. And I also don't want to require the users to use Yahoo!. I don't see anything other than a Jarain-specific thing on their [http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled](OpenID page).

Comment: http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/mobile -> Janrain Engage is optimized to support mobile platforms such as the iPhone and iPad, enabling you to login users to your application via their social network accounts such as Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo! or LinkedIn.

Comment: I do not want to log in with Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo! or LinkedIn. I want to log in with OpenID to my own provider.