# how to integrate yahoo,google and openID in an iphone application

Tags: ios4

I'm doing an application where user can get his list of events from the server by giving local credentials. I want to make my application run when the user enters google,yahoo and OpenId credentials. How can integrate that to my application.

Comment: Some example code is posted in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448863/can-we-implement-a-openid-options-in-a-native-iphone-app