# Login through Web view

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am developing an app for an existing website.My requirement is like this :User will login into app through WebView.  Now I want to  get back the response from webview weather login is successful or not.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5006679/279890

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117713/passing-data-to-and-from-an-embedded-uiwebview

Answer (score 1):

you can use [XWebView](https://github.com/XWebView/XWebView)

1.download XWebView using CocoaPods

edit your Podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
use_frameworks!
pod 'XWebView', '~> 0.9.2'
```

2.pod install

3.modify your ViewController viewDidLoad() method

```
let webview = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
view.addSubview(webview)
webview.loadPlugin(LoginNotify(), namespace: "loginNotify")
let root = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL!
let url = root.URLByAppendingPathComponent("index.html")
webview.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessToURL: root)
```

4.create LoginNotify class receive login message in LoginNotify group
import Foundation
import UIKit

```
class LoginNotify : NSObject {
    func show(text: AnyObject?) {
        let title = text as? String
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: title, message: nil, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }
    }
}
```

5.create index.html in LoginNotify group

```
// when login success use loginNofidy.show notify your swift part
loginNotify.show("login success!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the complete solution (workaround), but it this might help:

`UIWebView` has an event handler `LoadStarted`
Maybe you can try to find out to which page it is navigating to whenever `LoadStarted` is triggered. And based on that URL, you may be able to decide if the login was successful or not.

Or make the website navigate to a certain page (if the website is your)

I'm not an iOS developer, so I dont know about this- if the UIWebView internally uses the `LoadRequest` method to navigate, you should override it and then get the URL from `NSUrlRequest` object